# powershell service if scripts

Tags: powershell, if-statement, service

I am trying to right a script to check if a services is running on one of our servers if the services are running just write an event log, but if the services are stopped run another script outside of this script. I am running to issues with verifying if the services are running. I am sure it's simple but I am not that proficient in if statements. Any help is much appreciated.

> # Service Status
>
> ```
> $Service='Spooler'
>
> # Check service
>
>    ((get-service $service).Status -eq 'Running')
>
> $Service2='VMTools'
>
> ((get-service $service2).Status -eq 'Running')
> ```
>
> #### Execute Restarting Script if Stopped Service
>
> {
>         if ($service.Status -eq 'Stopped')
>         $service = False
>       {
>
> ```
>   elseif($Service2.Status -eq 'Stopped')
>  "$service2 = False"
> }
> else {
> ```
>
> Z:\SeviceRestart.ps1
>
> } } Write-EventLog -LogName "Service_TestScript" -Source
>   "Service_TestScript" -EventId 1 -Message "Verified $service ,
>   $service2 are running"
>
> ***My script now***
>
> ## Service Status
>
> $Service='Ipswitch SSH Server'
>
> $Service2='Ipswitch WS_FTP Server'
>
> function RestartServiceIfStopped([string]$service) {
>         $serviceStatus = (Get-Service $service).Status
>         if ($serviceStatus -eq 'Stopped'){
>              Start-Service -displayname $service
>              Write-Host "Started $service"
>         }
>         elseif ($serviceStatus -eq 'Running'){
>              Write-Host "Service $service is running"
>         }
>
> ## Write-EventLog -logname application -source MyApplication -eventid 1 -message "$service is running" }
>
> $hostname = 'FTP02'
>
> $smtpServer = '####'
>
> function SendMailMessageIFStopped([string]$service)
>
> {
>         $serviceStatus = (Get-Service $service).Status
>         if ($serviceStatus -eq 'Stopped'){
>               Send-MailMessage -To '####' -Subject "Restarting Printspooler Service on $hostname" -Body "This is an automated message
>   to confirm that the $Service , $Service2 service on $hostname 
>               is about to be restarted as part of failure, after recieving this message please check system to confirm." -From
>   test@test.com -SmtpServer $smtpServer } }
>
> RestartServiceIfStopped "Ipswitch SSH Server"
>
> RestartServiceIfStopped 'Ipswitch WS_FTP Server'
>
> Write-EventLog -Entrytype Warning -LogName "Service_TestScript"
>   -Source "Service_TestScript" -EventId 1 -Message "Verified $service , $service2 are running"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your script

```
function RestartServiceIfStopped([string]$service)
{
      $serviceStatus = (Get-Service $service).Status
      if ($serviceStatus -eq 'Stopped'){
           Start-Service -displayname $service
           Write-Host "Started $service"
      }
      elseif ($serviceStatus -eq 'Running'){
           Write-Host "Service $service is running"
      }
#Write-EventLog -logname application -source MyApplication -eventid 1 -message "$service is running"
}

RestartServiceIfStopped "Spooler"
```

For EventLog, you will have to create an event source using New-EventLog cmdlet (once per host).

Comment: Thank you for your help, when I execute this recommendation I am not getting this output 
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> Z:\ServiceCheck.ps1
At Z:\ServiceCheck.ps1:28 char:1
+ }
+ ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

I also need to monitor 3 services.

Comment: If the Service spool is not running I get that error, the script only works when the service is running, so it isn't doing a check against the status.

Comment: Tried detecting a service that is not running.  It worked fine.  Note that you need to provide Display Name of your service.  If you have multiple services, you can execute RestartServiceIfStopped multiple times

Comment: I don't know why it comes up with that error I was using the 'Spooler' Service on my account for testing Here is the error

Start-Service : Cannot find any service with display name 'Spooler'.
At Z:\ServiceCheck.ps1:17 char:12
+            Start-Service -displayname $service
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Spooler:String) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenDisplayName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
 
Started Spooler
Service VMTools is running

Comment: This is because the service does not exists.  The script requires Display Name and not the name of exe

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out I had to put the Send-MailMessage under the first IF-statement

Thank you for your help Punit Ganshani MVP

> ## Service Status
>
> $Service='Print Spooler' $Service2='VMTools' $hostname = 'FTP02'
>   $smtpServer = '****'
>
> function RestartServiceIfStopped([string]$service) {
>         $serviceStatus = (Get-Service $service).Status
>         if ($serviceStatus -eq 'Stopped'){
>              Start-Service -displayname $service
>              Write-Host "Started $service"
>              Send-MailMessage -To 'test@test.com,' -Subject
>   "Restarting $service and $service2 Service on $hostname" -Body "This
>   is an automated message to confirm that the $Service , $Service2
>   service on $hostname is about to be restarted as part of failure,
>   after recieving this message please check system to confirm." -From
>    -SmtpServer $smtpServer
>         }
>         elseif ($serviceStatus -eq 'Running'){
>              Write-Host "Service $service is running"
>         }
>         {
>          $serviceStatus = (Get-Service $service2).Status
>         if ($serviceStatus -eq 'Stopped'){
>              Start-Service -displayname $service2
>              Write-Host "Started $service2"
>         }
>         elseif ($serviceStatus -eq 'Running'){
>              Write-Host "Service $service2 is running"
>         } } } RestartServiceIfStopped "Print Spooler" RestartServiceIfStopped 'VMTools'
>
> Write-EventLog -Entrytype Warning -LogName "Service_TestScript"
>   -Source "Service_TestScript" -EventId 1 -Message "Verified $service , $service2 are running"